# Return rows where one row has a value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that looks as follows:

```
DepartmentID  DepartmentTierID   AllDepartmentTierID
----------------------------------------------------
1             NULL               25           
1             26                 26 
1             NULL               27
2             NULL               28
2             NULL               29 
2             30                 30 
3             NULL               31
3             NULL               32 
3             NULL               33
```

If there is a value in the DepartmentTierID in any of the records for a specific DepartmentID,  I need to return all the AlldepartmentTierIDs for that department. If there is no DepartmentTierID for a specific DepartmentID no AllDepartmentTiersIDs should return.
In other words, DepartmentID 1 would return 25,26 and 27. DepartmentID 2 would return 28,29 and 30 and and DepartmentID 3 wuld return nothing.

The resulting dataset should look as follows:

```
   AllDepartmentTierID
    -------------------
    25           
    26 
    27
    28
    29 
    30
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WHERE EXISTS` for this:

```
Select  AllDepartmentTierId
From    YourTable   T1
Where Exists
(
    Select  *
    From    YourTable   T2
    Where   T1.DepartmentId = T1.DepartmentId
    And     T2.DepartmentTierId Is Not Null
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT A.AllDepartmentTierID
FROM dbo.YourTable A
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.YourTable
             WHERE DepartmentID = A.DepartmentID
             AND DepartmentTierID IS NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is using window function:

```
select
    AllDepartmentTierID
from (
    select
        AllDepartmentTierID,
        max(DepartmentTierID) over (partition by DepartmentID) x
    from t
) t where x is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using `Count() Over()` window aggregate function.

```
Select * from
(
select *,count(DepartmentTierID) over(partition by DepartmentID) as cnt from yourtable 
) A
Where cnt >= 1
```

**How it works**

`Count` aggregate will not count `NULL` values so when count is greater than one it means the `DepartmentID` is having atleast one not null `DepartmentTierID`

Answer (score 0):

You would want to do something like this.  Please check, this was not tested.

SELECT  AllDepartmentTierID 
FROM    Department 
WHERE   DepartmentID  IN( 
SELECT DepartmentID
    FROM Department d
    WHERE d.DepartmentTierID <> NULL)